# Convert dictionary that is present inside two lists into a csv

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

My results set in inside two lists. How can i easily convert them to a csv?

```
fin= [[ {'name':'value','age':'value','addr':'value'},
   {'name':'value','age':'value','addr':'value'},
   {'name':'value','age':'value','addr':'value'}
]]
```

```
res_csv= pd.DataFrame(fin)
res_csv.to_csv(file.csv)

when i do this, the whole data is getting skewed inside a single line.

Am i doing something incorrect here? Seeking help from the Dev community
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a nested list, but with only one item - the list you need to load into your dataframe. So you can simply load that list by loading the first (and only) item of that list `fin[0]`.

```
fin= [[ {'name':'value','age':'value','addr':'value'},
   {'name':'value','age':'value','addr':'value'},
   {'name':'value','age':'value','addr':'value'}
]]
res_csv= pd.DataFrame(fin[0])
res_csv.to_csv('file.csv')
```

Comment: Eggs on my face!!! this didn't flash me yet so easy!! thank you so much pal

Answer (score 2):

Why use such a heavy tool like pandas for a simple csv:

```
import csv

with open("file.csv", "w") as f:
    w = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=fin[0][0].keys())
    w.writerows(fin[0])
```

Comment: Thank you mate!! I highly appreciate your effort :)..God bless

Comment: pandas are much more handy to handle these i feel. You can evade the looping and stuffs like that.

Comment: I feel you. If you already have Pandas as a dependency for data analysis anyway, go use it. But pls never install Pandas purely for csv handling =) Also no loop in this code.

Comment: what's your reasoning behind avoiding pandas for basic file writing purpose? I use pandas pretty for easy file writing and stuffs. Does panda got any overhead on the overall code performance or anything?